# Why is ‘karma’ cognate with ‘Britain’?

Tags: cognates

The word *karma* has Sanskrit origin. It ultimately comes from the PIE root **kʷer-* which means "to do or make". The word *karma* is cognate with *Britain*. I know what the word *karma* means (good or bad behavior being reciprocated), but I don’t see the semantic connection on the Latin side. What happened to Britain? I think it has to do with the meaning "do or make", but I don’t know what sense or why.

**UPD:** Here is [a reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/k%CA%B7er-) to *Britain* being a descendant of PIE **kʷer-*. See closer to the end of the page in the **Unsorted formations** section.

Comment: *The word karma is cognate with Britain* - any reference for this claim?

Comment: As a basic requirement for this question to be even remotely convincing in its assumptions, I suggest you give a PIE reconstruction of *Britain*. If you’re claiming that *Britain* also came from PIE \*kwer, you should give an etymological trace from *Britain* to \*kwer.

Comment: Wikipedia [explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britain_(place_name)#Etymology) the etymology of _Britain_ as derived from the Celtic word for Britons which meant "the painted, tattooed ones", which can well be connected with the meaning of the PIE root _*kʷer-_ "to do, make" as "the done, the made ones". Have you checked this article? If so, why doesn't that explanation suit you?

Comment: I think it would be better if it was written "how", not "why"

Comment: @ErgativeMan, that would presuppose that there was an explanation. The question rather asks why wiktionary had chosen to index it like that, whoever they referenced. "How" should rather ask "how likely"? I don't know I don't see the difference

Answer (score -3):

On the face of it, there is no good answer. Ethonymy is literally *folk etymology*.

This does not give the curious etymologist a free pass to speculate wildly, but the semantics reflecting *kʷer- (as per your wikilink) vary so wildly that it looks like speculation to beginn with. This suits me well, because I want to elaborate an idea.

Pretext: Some labial plosives reconstruct labial velars in some languages (Greek, P-Celtic, some Italic tongues, ...). Greek *kephale* has not been related to Latin *caput*, which seems odd; wiktionary reconstructs *gʰebʰ-, and *kaput- respectively. Trying to ameliorate these, and always on a quest for German *ge-*, Lat. *co-, PIE *'ke-, *'kom, I did not get very far. I searched my Lexicon and at Greek *bous*, *gʷṓws the admittedly haphazard thought for *ge-* reappeared. Labio velars can occasionally come from *K + *w, so trying to separate the labial element from the velar I was grabbing for a straw. The nearest lexeme in my mind was still *bous*. I reason thus, a labiovelar can also come from *K + *b (or *b^h). That was not was I was looking for at all. Now to your question.

1. *kʷer- lists a Hittite reflex "to cut", and several others. It also lists synonyms *yeh₁- and *h₂er-. The latter reinforces my assumption that *kʷer- can have an internal derivation.
2. Following the pretext, look for *b(h) roots suitable for comparison; check 
   *bʰardʰéh₂, *bʰeh₁-, bʰeh₂-, *bʰreyH-, in that order. *bʰreyH- "to cut" rings a bell, of course.

Sure enough I can imagine backstories towards *Briton* for any given sense, but that's besides the point, I don't want to speculate. I only looked at *bʰreyH- because the link in the root index was dark-colored, visited before, but I didn't remember. That means it's a wild guess, except that *-r- clicked. Hence any further elaboration comes as an afterthought. Hittite is supposedly most archaic evidence, so I'm leaning more on the semantic side of it. Hittite also reflects *bʰreyH- but that doesn't change anything.

It only means that the root of Britain might go back a long way, and that a semantic interpretation is as good as irrecoverable without timely material evidence, because a loose semantic interpretation can always be given.

Point in case: a) To incorporate the Tattoo interpretation that wikipedia offers, suppose that roots meaning to write often come from "to cut", and tattoos are a form of writing. b) consider "Balto-Slavic: *kēr-, *ker-[4]
Lithuanian: kẽras (“charm, magic”), kerė́ti (“to enchant, charm, bewitch”), kùrti (“to do, make, build”)
Slavic: *čarъ (“magic, sorcery”), *čara (“magic, sorcery”)[4]" [wiktionary] to compare *karma* and *charm*, Latin *carmen*, Old Latin *casmen* "song", ety uncertain (*kenh2?); if the *s* seems to contradict the attempt, assume *carsmen and move on to Celtic. c) How many Sanskrit words in *bhr-* do you know? I know *Brahmin*, assume "scribe"(?), actually "high, lofty". That's *bʰerǵʰ-, which lists PCelt *brixtu, that is in Matasovich as "magical formula, incantation", indeed, Breton *brith*, PIE *bʰerǵʰ- "enlighten ?". But wait, it get's better. Your link lists PCelt Celtic *kʷritus
"Old Irish: cruth (“form”)
Welsh: pryd (“form, time”), prydaf (“compose poetry, versify”)". Matasovich has Celtic: *kʷritus
"magical incantation, form".

There's further "word", "judgement", under *b- *br-, but also "robber" (German *Einbrecher*?), a word "drinking cup", *pela*-[gasi?], Ger. *gebrauchen* "use", *prepare*, ...

It seems the cognate under Celtic: *kʷritus do not quite allow the given interpretation, but I will take it for the time being. What a fantastic journey. Thanks for the invitation.